# How to import an algorithm built in Python to H2O?

Tags: h2o

I have a requirement to add new algorithms built in Python/Java to H2O and making it available in Flow UI. I have not found much information other than these old posts

- https://groups.google.com/g/h2ostream/c/lFXdizcgemE?pli=1
- https://www.h2o.ai/blog/hacking-algorithms-into-h2o-quantiles/

Please let me know if there is a way to do it. I don't think these articles are still relevant. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Article https://www.h2o.ai/blog/hacking-algorithms-into-h2o-quantiles/ is still relevant, some details changed by the main concept remained the same.

Everything you read about map-reduce and DKV is still relevant to this day. The foundation of the article didn't change.

We will refresh the article to make it up to date with the current code base.

Answer (score 0):

I already added an example of extending H2O: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/pull/6070

It gives you a skeleton of the implementation of H2O algorithm.